# WinRM listening on incorrect IP

Tags: server, configuration, port, listener, winrm

I have a server where I have configured WinRM using the IP address and HTTPS using the command below.

```
New-Item -Path WSMan:\LocalHost\Listener -Transport HTTPS -Address "IP:x.y.z.10" -CertificateThumbPrint "<ThumbPrint>" –Force
```

The listener shows OK using the WinRM command.

```
winrm e winrm/config/listener

Listener
    Address = IP:x.y.z.10
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname = ServerA
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = <ThumbPrint>
    ListeningOn = x.y.z.10
```

Pinging ServerA resolves to x.y.z.10

This server has two IPs x.y.z.10 (primary) and x.y.z.11 (secondary for a website).

When I check the IP and ports listening using tools like Currports, telnet, or PortQuery, I see that WinRM is listening on x.y.z.11.

I have tried all the following tricks to no avail.

1. Removed and/or re-installed IIS and default site etc.
2. Updated WinrRM to the latest (it is a Windows 2008 R2 server)
3. Removed the .11 IP from the server (after this it listened on
   127.0.0.1).
4. Made sure that default website has id of 1
5. Tried registering an http-only listener (it still listens on .11 even
   though IP used in the new-item command is .10).
6. Removed expired certs
7. Made sure that "Skip as Source" is set to false for .10 and true for
   .11

Based on my research so far, it seems that somehow WinRM is not seeing the server default IP of .10.

Any suggestion where should I look next?

I have configured about 50 other servers successfully using the same config, but there is something unique about the default IP on this server that I can't wrap my head around.

Thanks for any help!